# Spark Dataframe withColumn When Otherwise condition Not Working in Spark Java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In a spark dataframe, i am trying to assign a column value based on another column value on different conditions using withColumn When Otherwise logic in Spark Java.

The input has 3 records which has 3 red, yellow and green as the values in column CODE respectively.

Below is the logic i am using in Spark Java:

```
df = df.withColumn("TYPE",
((Column) when(df.col("CODE").$eq$bang$eq("RED"),(functions.lit("X")))
.when(df.col("CODE").$eq$bang$eq("YELLOW"),(functions.lit("X")))
.when(df.col("CODE").$eq$bang$eq("GREEN"),(functions.lit("Y"))))
.otherwise(functions.lit("N")).alias("TYPE"));
```

Below is the result i am getting:

```
+---------+----------+
|CODE     |TYPE      |
+---------+----------+
|red      |X         |
|yellow   |X         |
|green    |X         |
+---------+----------+
```

Instead of getting X,X,Y as TYPE, i am getting all values as X.
It is not checking the equality, it is just assigning the first value from the lit function.

e.g. Even if i give random string('asdfgh') inside the check condition(although it is false), but still it is assigning the first value 'X'.

```
df = df.withColumn("TYPE",
((Column) when(df.col("CODE").$eq$bang$eq("asdfgh"),(functions.lit("X")))
.when(df.col("CODE").$eq$bang$eq("YELLOW"),(functions.lit("X")))
.when(df.col("CODE").$eq$bang$eq("GREEN"),(functions.lit("Y"))))
.otherwise(functions.lit("N")).alias("TYPE"));
```

Result is same as above result

NOTE: Column 'TYPE' is a new column i want to add to the df and 'CODE' is an existing column.

Please help in fixing the logic

Answer (score 0):

The above given logic can somewhat be represented in the following manner using if-else :

```
if (col("CODE") =!= "RED"){
    return "X"
}
else if (col("CODE") =!= "YELLOW") {
    return "X"
}
else if (col("CODE") =!= "GREEN") {
    return "Y"
}
else
{
    return "N"
}
```

On dry running this code firstly, with an example input where CODE = "RED".The output will be "X" generated from :

```
else if (col("CODE") =!= "YELLOW") {
        return "X"
    }
```

Secondly , given CODE = "YELLOW" .The output generated will be "X" from this block :

```
if (col("CODE") =!= "RED"){
        return "X"
    }
```

Thirdly , given CODE = "GREEN" . The output generated will be "X" and not "Y" as this block will be executed as "GREEN" =!= "RED" evaluates to true:

```
if (col("CODE") =!= "RED"){
        return "X"
    }
```

I don't think there is a way to attain the desired output as we are using enequalities as `$eq$bang$eq` should evaluate to `"=!="` . The desired output can be attained by equality operator `===`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I cannot use the above syntax in spark java

Comment: The above answer was to explain the logic i.e. with $eq$bang$eq (=!=) the desired output won't be generated .I am still not clear what is intended to be done is it =!= or === . Once it's clear then only the code part can be answered . Thanks